# php - extract array into global variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables, extract, global

[The manual on "extract"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) shows you can extract an array like:

```
extract(array('one'=>1,'two'=>2));
```

into $one,$two...

But the extract function doesn't return the variables. Is there a way to 'globalize' these variables? Maybe not using extract, but a foreach loop?

**EDIT:** (explanation about what I'm trying to achieve)
I have an array containing hundreds of output messages which I want to have accessible as variables efficiently. What I mean is that whenever I want to output a message, say:

```
$englishMessages = array('helloWorld'=>'Hello World');
$spanishMessages = array('helloWorld'=>'Hola Mundo');
'<span id="some">'. $helloWorld .'</span>';
```

The message would appear. The reason I'm doing it like this is so that users can change the language they're viewing the website in, so something like:
    ''. $helloWorld .'';
would produce:

```
Hola Mundo!
```

Comment: Global variables and extract() are two of my least favorite parts of PHP... so, this question made me throw up a little in my mouth. Can solve your application problem another way?

Comment: @ojrac: absolutely, I edit with a more elaborate explanation.

Comment: I'm rusty on the syntax, but here's an idea: $language = get_lang('en'), and then "<span>${language['helloWorld']}</span>"

Comment: @ojrac, the reason I didn't use this to begin with is because I want to use variables, not an array.

Comment: Hey, [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) is perfect, see @code_burgar answer. Another "PHP way" is `list($a,$b,...)=$array` (!). I not see why you need more than this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly an answer to your question  ...but: Keep the array, don't pollute the (global) variable namespace.

```
$englishMessages = array('helloWorld'=>'Hello World');
$spanishMessages = array('helloWorld'=>'Hola Mundo');

// wrap this in a nice function/method
$lang = $englishMessages;
// then use $lang for the output
'<span id="some">'. $lang['helloWorld'] .'</span>';
```

Some variations on the same theme:

```
function getMessages($language) {
  static $l = array(
    'en'=> array('helloWorld'=>'Hello World'),
    'es' => array('helloWorld'=>'Hola Mundo')
  );
  // <-- add handling reporting here -->
  return $l[$language];
}

$lang = getMessages('en');
echo '<span id="some">'. $lang['helloWorld'] .'</span>';
```

or

```
function __($language, $id) {
  static $l = array(
    'en'=> array('helloWorld'=>'Hello World'),
    'es' => array('helloWorld'=>'Hola Mundo')
  );
  // <-- add error handling here -->
  return $l[$language][$id];
}

echo '<span id="some">'. __('es', 'helloWorld') .'</span>';
```

You might also be interested in http://docs.php.net/gettext

Comment: do you suggest not making $lang global?

Comment: Neither $lang itself nor its elements, yes. Just use a function/method that returns an array.

Comment: -1: Didn't answer the question. If you want to admonish the person asking the question better to answer the question and then tell them why not to use it because there's a chance someone wants to use it for a valid use-case _(such as to work compatibly with an existing CMS.)_

Comment: @MikeSchinkel : I agree with your point of view in general, but choose not to act accordingly in this paraticular case and just accept the downvote. I'd rather that this "answer" hadn't been marked as "accepted", as usual when I start with "not really/exactly an answer to your question" ;-)

Answer (score 5):

```
 $GLOBALS += $vars;
```

for example

```
function foo() {
  $vars = array('aa' => 11, 'bb' => 22);
  $GLOBALS += $vars;
}

foo();
echo $aa; // prints 11
```

that said, can you explain why you need this? Using global variables is considered poor style, maybe there's a better way

Comment: I have an array containing hundreds of variables=>output messages.
Do you think there's a better practice for this? (I don't want these messages to be constants because they might have to be changed).

Answer (score 3):

You mean:

```
 foreach($array as $var_name => $var_value)
 {
       global $$var_name;
       $$var_name = $var_value;
 }
```

This will global each variable, and then set it to your value. For yours it would create `$one`, and `$two`

Comment: If your global variable happens to be named `$var_value`, you'll have a clash with the local variable `$var_value`. So better assign `$GLOBALS[$var_name] = $var_value;`.

Answer (score 2):

using extract() on an array will create new variables inside the current scope, or assign new values to existing variables.

I'm not sure what you mean by "globalize", but my understanding is that you are trying to accomplish exactly what extract() does, just be mindful of the current scope (if you extract() from within a function, the extracted variables will only be available inside the function itself).

Comment: for reference, in case im ever searching again for this ... `extract` works with assoc-array, use `list` for indexed arrays

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  // initialize the variables as global
   global $$key;
   $$key = $value;
}
```

#### EDIT:

Just noticed a mistake of mine, you'd have to make the key of the array into a variable, which can be done by converting it to a [**variable variables**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) using `$$` notation.

Comment: This doesn't work, as `$key` will only be the value of the last item in the array.

Comment: If your global variable is named `$value`, you'll have a clash with the local variable `$value`. So better assign `$GLOBALS[$key] = $value;`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the variables that have been extracted? You can find them using [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-keys.php)