# how to Extract variables without using extract()?

Tags: php

I would like a function to export variables to the scope it's called within without using extract(), e.g.

```
function get_vars(){
  $return['a'] = 1;
  $return['b'] = 2
  return $return;
}
```

and then rather than using :

```
exctract(get_vars());
```

I would just use

```
get_vars();
```

is there anyway available??

Comment: can you add a bit more detail to your question?

Comment: extract eh? Weird and kind of unsettling :) I'm guessing you want to extract those into global variables. Perhaps check this link out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217377/php-extract-array-into-global-variables

Answer (score 0):

Saw that possible solution at the php manuel of the extract function.
(http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php#62727)

```
function free_args (&$V) {
    foreach ($V as $k => &$v) {
        $$k =& $v;
    }
    unset ($k);  unset ($v);  unset ($V);

    // be careful that if you need to extract $k, $v or $V variables you should find other names for them in the lines above (ie. $__k, $__v and $__V)
}
```

Comment: I think the above example differs from what i originally wanted, thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `global` keyword

```
function get_vars() {
  global $a, $b;
  $a = 1;
  $b =2;
}
```

But as for me, it is a very weird approach. I prefer to use OOP.